# Hide form input fields from URL

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I've got a login form with two input fields: username and password.

```
<form method="get" action="../Main/Index">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" maxlength="30"></p>
    <p>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password" maxlength="25"></p>

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Enter">
    </p>

</form>
```

Once the user submits the form, his username and password are shown in the browser's URL textbox, something like this:

`http://localhost:53997/Main/Index?username=zm&password=123456789&commit=Enter`

I don't want his username and password to be on display.

How can I do this?

Comment: use form method="POST". this will send the same data but as payload and not in url.

Comment: Thank you @gp.. Answer the question so I can accept as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is that youre using `form method = "get"` when you should be using `form method = "post"` instead.

this explains it:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee784233(v=cs.20).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee784233%28v=cs.20%29.aspx)